# Use callback get executed when value is the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that every time I move the mouse he recomputes the position of a vertical line on the dom, that position move of the cursor also causes some side effects that make a static text above to always re-render.

To prevent that I tried to make use of **Use Callback hook** like below:

```
const renderSection = useCallback(() => {
  console.log('title: ', title);
  return (
    <Header>
      <HeaderTitle>{title}</HeaderTitle>
    </Header>
  );
}, [title]);
```

and then I just return it on my function:

```
return (
  {renderSection()}
)
```

Somehow even when the title is the same, the console log gets executed and I see the same title over again, I specified the title as the dependency for the callback, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong any help?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are looking for `React.memo()` and not for `useCallback()`. What you have is not a callback, it's a function.

Comment: You are right, it worked, I don't understand very well the difference between both :/. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**useCallback** uses when you provide function (callback) to child component. For example:

```
const Parent = () => {
   const [value, setValue] = useState()

   const handleChange = useCallback((newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue)
   }, [dependencies])

   return(
      <Input onChange={handleChange} value={value} />
   )
}

const Input = /* Input component */

export default React.memo(Input)
```

Since we pass a function (callback) to the Input, at each render, the link to the function in the component will change, although its contents have not changed. React will think that the properties have changed. `useCallback` allows you to save a link to a function until the dependencies declared in **dependencies** have changed. Thus, wrapping the `Input` into a `React.memo` and using `useCallback`, we can avoid unnecessary re-renders.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you want is the `useMemo` hook.

```
const renderSection = useMemo(() => {
  console.log('title: ', title);
  return (
    <Header>
      <HeaderTitle>{title}</HeaderTitle>
    </Header>
  );
}, [title]);
```

and your return

```js
return (
    {renderSection}
)
```